# Ошибка Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (InstrFetchProhibited) после отправки строки

Tags: сеть, сокет, arduino, микроконтроллеры, esp32

Строю проект, частью которого выступает сокет-сервер на ESP32. Сценарий, при котором выбрасывается эта ошибка, следующий: в сокет приходит строка `{CHON}`, происходит успешная обработка этой строки, ESP32 включает необходимое реле и отвечает `CHON`, после чего выбрасывается Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (InstrFetchProhibited) и ESP32 перезагружается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как справиться с этой ошибкой.
Код выглядит следующим образом:

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
 
 // Определяем максимальное количество клиентов, которые могут подключиться к этому серверу (обычно не более 4)
#define MAX_SRV_CLIENTS 5

 // Следующие три определения являются определениями отладки
#define DebugBegin(baud_rate)    Serial.begin(baud_rate)
#define DebugPrintln(message)    Serial.println(message)
#define DebugPrint(message)      Serial.print(message)
#define DebugPrintf(message)     Serial.printf(message)

int firstRelay = 5;
int secondRelay = 14;
 
const char* ssid = "Keenetic-6370";
const char* password = "vxTuT5JT";
 
 // Создаем номер порта сервера 80
WiFiServer server(80);
 // Управление клиентами
WiFiClient serverClients[MAX_SRV_CLIENTS];

long pushtime = 0;
 
void setup()
{
  pinMode(firstRelay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(firstRelay, HIGH);
  pinMode(secondRelay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(secondRelay, HIGH);
  
  DebugBegin(115200);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  DebugPrint("\nConnecting to "); 
  DebugPrintln(ssid);
  uint8_t i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && i++ < 30)
  {
    DebugPrint("."); 
    delay(500);
  }
  if (i == 21) 
  {
    DebugPrint("Could not connect to"); 
    DebugPrintln(ssid);
    while (1) 
    {
      delay(500);
    }
  }

  server.begin();   // Запускаем сервер
  server.setNoDelay(true);    // Отключаем функцию объединения небольших пакетов, без задержки при отправке данных
 
  DebugPrint("Ready! Use 'telnet ");
  DebugPrint(WiFi.localIP());
  DebugPrintln(" 80' to connect");
  pushtime = millis();
}
 
void loop()
{
  uint8_t i;
  if (server.hasClient())   // Определяем, поступает ли новый клиентский запрос
  {
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++)   // Освобождаем старого недействительного или отключенного клиента
    {
      if (!serverClients[i] || !serverClients[i].connected())
      {
        if (serverClients[i])
        {
          serverClients[i].stop();
        }
        serverClients[i] = server.available();    // Назначаем последнего клиента
        DebugPrint("New client: "); 
        DebugPrintln(i);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (i == MAX_SRV_CLIENTS)   // Когда максимальное количество подключений достигнуто, подключение необходимо отклонить
    {
      WiFiClient serverClient = server.available();
      serverClient.stop();
      DebugPrintln("Connection rejected ");
    }
  }
 
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++)   // Обнаружение данных, отправленных клиентом
  {
    if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
      if (serverClients[i].available())
      {
        String inString;
        while (serverClients[i].available())    //get data from the telnet client and push it to the UART
        {
          char inChar = serverClients[i].read();
          inString += inChar;
          delay(5);
          if (inChar == '}')
          {
            inString = "\n" + inString;
            if (inString.indexOf("{GLAVIARY}")>0)  // свет в навесе
            {
              digitalWrite(firstRelay, !digitalRead(firstRelay));
            }
            else if (inString.indexOf("{CHON}")>0)  // свет в домике куриц on
            {
              digitalWrite(secondRelay, LOW);
              for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++)   // Отправляем данные каждому клиенту
              {
                if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected())
                {
                  serverClients[i].println("CHON");   // ПРЕДПОЛАГАЕМОЕ МЕСТО ОШИБКИ!!!
                  delay(5);
                }
              }
            }
            else
            {
              Serial.println("Wrong command");
            }
            inString = "";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Так выглядит сама ошибка:
[image: Так выглядит сама ошибка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью гугла нашел 2 возможных ошибки:

1. Проблемы с питанием.
2. Попытка доступа в недоступную память.

Как оказалось, я действительно пытался попасть в недоступную память, из-за выхода за пределы массива. На самом деле из-за простой невнимательности в месте, где один цикл for выполняется в другом цикле for, оба цикла работают на одном счетчике `i` при одинаковых условиях. Таким образом после выполнения внутреннего цикла следующая итерация внешнего не может быть начата из-за того, что переменная `i` не удовлетворяет условиям. Поэтому решением оказалось создание собственной переменной счетчика для внутреннего цикла.

Рабочий фрагмент кода:

```java
for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++)   // Обнаружение данных, отправленных клиентом
{
  if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
    if (serverClients[i].available())
    {
      String inString;
      while (serverClients[i].available())    //get data from the telnet client and push it to the UART
      {
        char inChar = serverClients[i].read();
        inString += inChar;
        delay(5);
        if (inChar == '}')
        {
          inString = "\n" + inString;
          if (inString.indexOf("{GLAVIARY}")>0)  // свет в навесе
          {
            digitalWrite(firstRelay, !digitalRead(firstRelay));
          }
          else if (inString.indexOf("{CHON}")>0)  // свет в домике куриц on
          {
            digitalWrite(secondRelay, LOW);
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; j++)   // Отправляем данные каждому клиенту
            {
              if (serverClients[j] && serverClients[j].connected())
              {
                serverClients[j].println("CHON");
                delay(5);
              }
            }
          }
          else
          {
            Serial.println("Wrong command");
          }
          inString = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

На самом деле, как мне кажется, ошибка все равно не должна была произойти, так как внешний цикл просто не должен был начать следующую итерацию, но почему-то происходит именно ошибка.

Но даже если бы ошибка не возникала код, указанный в вопросе работал бы не так как задумано, поэтому решение исправляет все проблемы.